# How to close a `Userform` after clicking a button

Tags: vba, userform

I have a Corel Draw issue using `Exit Sub` to close a `Userform` after clicking a button.

It will run the script to completion, but  won't execute the `Exit Sub` command.

[image]

I tried setting a dummy variable to a true value `If X=1 then Exit Sub` but that didn't do the trick either.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox "Script Ran!"
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

My hope is to click a button, and have the userform close after it runs. My impression was `Exit Sub` is the way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`Exit Sub` functions as an exit point of the current Sub.
Having it before `End Sub` does literally nothing except leaving the Sub one line earlier.

What you want is `Unload Me`.
See the relevant VBA documentation of the [Unload Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/unload-statement).